# Access denied home page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I wanted to remove permission only to one library, but due to my lack of knowladge I deleted permission to whole group of user. When I reasigned permission they can still can't log in to home page. They do have permission to the other sites but have "access denied" erorr in mian page. How can I fix it? I simply removed user permision from one library and it had impact on whole SP site. And when I had restored it users can't log in into ghome page.
[image]

Comment: Make sure that users are there in appropriate group .. you have made changes in library,. so that should not affect on site... so please check the site groups & it's permissions...

Comment: I'm 100% sure that users are in that group.
1. I removed group from library,
2. Readded then
3. Nobody from that group have access to main site

Comment: You can user Check Permissions on site level to see to what users have access, have you granted the group you recreated same permission level?

Comment: I didn't recreated group. I jus deleted its permission and somehow they can't access home page. I meesed it up

Answer (score 0):

If users have permissions in the main site, check if the **Site Pages** library is inheritnig from the main site permissions.

Comment: Hey, how I can do that?

Comment: Go to Site Contents > Site Pages > Library Tab > Library Configuration > Manage Permissions. Site Pages Library is the Library where all your SharePoint site pages are stored by default. They probably don't have permission to your MainPage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check **Site Permissions**

- Go to *Site Settings* > *Site Permissions*
- Make sure that group is assigned.